# Sessions never expire in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-3.2, session-timeout

My sessions seem to never expire, even though I configured my session_store.rb file to have this code:

```
Barcadia::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
                                           :key => '_barcadia_session',
                                           :expire_after => 15.minutes
```

I want users to have to re-login if they have been idle for more than 15 minutes. I am using rails 3.2 and I've tried both cookie_store and active_record_store... Nothing seems to work.

Comment: you may have a look at your cookies expiring date at your browser. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i see missing are the brackets:

```
Barcadia::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
                                      :key => '_barcadia_session',
                                      :expire_after => 15.minutes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Some::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, {
  expire_after: 24.hours,
}
```

this worked for me